# AngularJS create another module and add it as dependency to first

Tags: angularjs, module

I have created an app.js file, this is my application.
I have also created with angular components some logic that can used for display and edit some data. In a few words, I have created 2 different components (grid, form) and some other subcomponents, I use that components like a black box. That means: in my Angular routing in controller state the only thing created is a configuration object and passed this to the components like arguments.
Now I include that components to my app, one by one and want to create something more reusable, like another Angular app module, that the second includes all components (black box) and my first app the only thing that needs to include is the second module. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like that?

```
angular.module('app', [
   'app.components'
])

angular.module('app.components', [
   'app.components.a',
   'app.components.b'
])

angular.module('app.components.a', [
   'something.here'
])

angular.module('app.components.a').directive('myComponentA', function(){
 return {
    config_here: true
 }
})

angular.module('app.components.b', [
  'something.here'
])

angular.module('app.components.b').directive('myComponentB', function(){
 return {
   config_here: true
 }
})
```

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Also You don't have to wrap component.A and component.B with 'app.components'. It's possible to add them as dependencies directly to other modules or 'app' module itself, whatever you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
angular.module('ParentModule', [ 
   'ChildModule_1',
   'ChildModule_2'
])
```